# why value of parameter inside void main function in C is initialised with 1?

Tags: c, turbo-c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>

void main(main) {
    clrscr();
    printf("%d",main +=pow(++main,++main));
    getch();
}
```

So, i have run the above code in turboC compiler n got the output 12. i have noticed here the value of main is always initialised with 1. so i want to know why its value is 1? why not anything else?? please anyone help me out :)

Note: i also tried to change the name of parameter "main" with something else like x,y etc.. the value still 1 and also output also same i.e 12.

Comment: How do you know `main` is initialized with `1`? Your code doesn't print `main`.

Comment: This code is seriously broken for a lot of reasons, but the answer ignoring all of that is that it’s taking on the usual value of the first `main` parameter when you have a correct signature `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`.

Comment: Unrelated: *"i have run the above code in turboC compiler"* - That toolchain is literally at least a decade older than *you are*. The only reason its still used in academia is because it runs on archaic hardware that is, likewise, just as old (and thus cheap). I sincerely hope the offerings of modern, *free* toolchains like clang and/or gcc someday find their way to your desktop.

Comment: Doing x+=pow(++x, ++x) is undefined behavior, you don't need to investigate since the result may vary depending on too many factors (compiler...)

Comment: regarding: `void main(main) {`   This is NOT a valid signature for `main()`  There are two valid signatures:  `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`   The posted signature for `main()` does not match either signature

Comment: @melpomene atleast try to run it . main is not a keyword bro. we can use it as a identifier although it is not a good practice.

Comment: @Ry- dude the code is all correct . it's just that you didn't understand that. and reason why am i asking here is that this question asked by Microsoft in interview.

Comment: @Nico238 thats why i mentioned turbo C compiler ;)

Comment: @user3629249 i know that was not a valid signature. that question was asked in the interview thats the reason why i am asking here

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal I never said anything about `main` being a keyword. I asked you a simple question. Also, Ry- is correct that the code is very broken.

Comment: I'm not going to download random executables from the internet and run them on my computer. Also, could you answer my question, please?

Comment: @melpomene ok bro no problem. by the way which question you are talking abt?

Comment: The very first sentence in the very first comment: "*How do you know `main` is initialized with `1`?*"

Comment: @melpomene okay. here main acts as a argc parameter . since no parameter is passed in the program thats why it is by default initialised with 1 as Eric mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In strictly conforming C code, main should be declared as one of the following or an equivalent:

```
int main(void)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

When `main` is declared with the latter, `argv` contains pointers to (the first characters of) strings, and `argc` contains the number of such pointers in `argv`. `argv[0]` represents the program name, and the following elements are parameters to the program.

Your compiler is accepting a very old syntax in which the type may be omitted in a declaration. So `int main(x)` declares `x` to be a parameter of type `int`. This is not strictly conforming C, but your compiler is accepting it.

When you run the program with no arguments, it is passed only the program name, in `argv[0]`. Since there is just the program name and no arguments, `argc` is set to 1.

Using `main` for the parameter name, as in `int main(main)`, is bad practice, but it has no special effects except that it causes the identifier “main” inside the function to refer to the parameter and not to the function.